# How can I convert the data from an image node into data for a mix node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I want to use a grayscale image to smoothly blend two shaders together onto one mesh using a mix shader and an image node. How can I convert the data from the image node into data for the mix shader?

Answer (score 3):

Plug the output of the image node into the *Mix Factor* of the mix node:

[image]

Comment: lol, I was just posting an answer. You just beat me :) There is a difference between a color and B&W input I find in my tests

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I seem to remember noticing that at one point, but I can't reproduce it now.. Anyway, I read the OP's question as already having a greyscale image.

Comment: Yeah, the whole convert thing threw me off a bit. I think what you posted is what they wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Hue/Saturation* node (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Color > Hue Saturation*). If you set the saturation to zero then the information will be black and white.

[image]

You could use the *RGB to BW* node to do this quicker <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Converter > RGB to BW*)

[image]

You can also switch the image to the non-color data type like so:

[image]

This for use with bump or normal maps and similar image files that have data other than colors. It can also help when using a standard image in such a way.

Comment: Note that there is an *RGB to BW* node which also can be used for desaturating things